# How do I connect the screen of a laptop as an external display?

Tags: laptop, lcd, external-display, laptop-display, modding

I do not want to use a functional laptop as a display.

I have a brand new replacement screen for a laptop that I would like to mod into my desktop computer case.  I want to connect it to the computer just like any other external display (ie: dvi cable into the video card)

My disconnect is at the conversion from the ribbon cable to dvi/vga/hdmi.

A full howto would be excellent but I'm really just hoping for search terms to lead me to a howto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I've found so far to do this is this [LCD Controller board](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LCD-Controller-board-for-DIY-a-laptop-a-desktop-monitor-/271008855606?pt=US_Server_Boards&hash=item3f1962f636). Here's also a youtube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lHnABxkk5s) that shows how it works

Comment: More specifically, what you want is to be able to convert the LVDS signal coming from the display into a DVI (or in the case of this particular controller, VGA) signal. There are a number of products that claim to do this.

Comment: @user55325 - You have the flow of information backwards.  The display requires the LVDS signal.  The DVI or VGA signal (from the PC) has to be converted to LVDS.  The PC *outputs* video to the display.  The only info that the display sends is its EDID *response*.

Comment: You're right, of course. :P